# Selecting multiple rows from one table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table structure

**id  name       value**
    1   questions   50
    2   duration    120

Now, i want to display the value according to the name. 
I am unable to do the sql statement correct. 
This is what i have done:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT (SELECT value FROM pq_examsettings) as duration,
       (SELECT value FROM pq_examsettings) as questions
 ) ";
$result= mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$duration = $row['duration'];
$questions = $row['questions'];
```

Somebody help me on how i can do my query such that my $duration and $questions variables display  120 and 50.

Comment: If this is a new project, look into using the mysqli extension rather than mysql.

Comment: Thanks @Pier-LucGendreau. I have noticed that they are deprecating mysql_ functions. I will convert to the mysqli extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'questions' THEN value END) questions,
        MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'duration' THEN value END) duration 
FROM    pq_examsettings
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli or pdo functions the mysql_* functions are officially deprecated:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbmanager, $dbpass, $dbname);
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Error connecting to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pq_examsettings");
if($query->num_rows){
$new_row = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'name'){
            $array_key = $value;
        }
        if($key == 'value'){
            $new_row[$array_key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
$duration = $new_row['duration'];
$questions = $new_row['questions'];
}
```

Comment: The `SELECT *` query won't help here - the question was how to get both values as two columns in a single row. Your query will deliver the results in two rows.

Comment: waa you can make a `foreach` statement

Comment: sorry, now it works as you want. and as I said try not to use mysql_* functions

Comment: @Memolition this works now. Thanks and thanks for the heads up on mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know a simple way to transpose rows to columns and return the results in one select-- looks like JW gave an answer that does that.

Another option would be to just make two database calls:

```
$qry = "SELECT value FROM PQ_EXAMSETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'duration'";
$result= mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$duration = $row['value'];

$qry = "SELECT value FROM PQ_EXAMSETTINGS WHERE NAME = 'questions'";
$result= mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$questions = $row['value'];
```

Comment: This also works well but the best way on my opinion, it is the way JW has done it.